# Coloring rows with longtable

Tags: tables, xetex, color

I am using longtable to draw a table that spans a few pages. I also added code to alternate colors for rows in the table.

1. Is there a way to colorize the first row with a different color?
2. How can I ensure that the caption string is not colorized?

My MWE is below

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{table}{xcolor}
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{longtable}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\newcounter{magicrownumbers}
\newcommand\rownumber{\stepcounter{magicrownumbers}\arabic{magicrownumbers}}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\definecolor{light-gray}{HTML}{E5E4E2}
\definecolor{light-cyan}{HTML}{E0FFFF}


\begin{document}
\def\arraystretch{1}
\begin{center}
\rowcolors{1}{light-cyan}{light-gray}
\begin{longtable}{|p{.10\textwidth}| p{.98\textwidth}| p{.10\textwidth}|} 

\hline
serial num. & sutra & sutra number   \\
\hline
\rownumber & foo &1-1-56 \\
\hline
\rownumber  & bar & 1-1-57  \\
\hline
\caption{caption for this table}
\end{longtable}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output from processing .tex file]

Comment: Is everything in your MWE necessary to reproduce the problem? I ask because you are setting a high bar for getting help right now: you require helpers to have installed Sanskrit 2003 (or to track it down and install it, purchasing it if required). That's quite a lot to expect for somebody to just figure out if they can even reproduce the issue.

Comment: @cfr I can edit my example and remove the parts that require Sanskrit2003. Sorry about that. I copy+pasted a portion of my latex source so that it is a good representation of what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Have you tried `\hiderowcolors`/`\showrowcolors`?

Comment: Your table is too wide for the page, by the way. You must get bad box warnings with this.

Comment: `\hiderowcolors` and `\showrowcolors` answers my question #2. Thanks. I'll fix the table width too.

Comment: `\rowcolor{}` will change the colour of a particular row, including a header row or a first header row. See example below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can change row colour with `\rowcolor{}` for the header rows and use `\hiderowcolors` and `\showrowcolors` to avoid colouring the caption.

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}

\definecolor{light-gray}{HTML}{E5E4E2}
\definecolor{light-cyan}{HTML}{E0FFFF}

\begin{document}
\rowcolors{1}{light-cyan}{light-gray}
\begin{longtable}{|*{3}{p{.3\textwidth}|}}
  \hiderowcolors
  \caption{Fine caption}\\
  \showrowcolors
  \hline
  \rowcolor{magenta}Head 1 & Head 2 & Head 3\\\hline\endfirsthead
  \hline
  \rowcolor{yellow}Head 1 & Head 2 & Head 3\\\hline\endhead
  \hline\endfoot
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image: colouring tables]

Note that I take no responsibility for failures of typographical aesthetics in this answer which should be understood as demonstrating how to implement a purely hypothetical set of desiderata.

That is, I don't recommend this and wouldn't do it, but if you must, you can.