# Coloring rows with longtable, and with multirows

Tags: tables, longtable, multicolumn, multicol, multirow

I am trying to add [**multirows**](https://texblog.org/2012/12/21/multi-column-and-multi-row-cells-in-latex-tables/) to this [**Coloring rows with longtable**](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/346143/coloring-rows-with-longtable).

How can I add multirows in this example?

This is my attempt:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\title{A random title}

% Add longtable and xcolor packages and define two colors
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{light-gray}{HTML}{E5E4E2}
\definecolor{light-cyan}{HTML}{E0FFFF}

% Add the multirow package
\usepackage{multirow, makecell}

\begin{document}
\maketitle


% Table
\rowcolors{1}{light-cyan}{light-gray}
\begin{longtable}{|*{3}{p{.3\textwidth}|}}
  \hiderowcolors
  \caption{Fine caption}\\
  \showrowcolors
  \hline
  \rowcolor{magenta}Head 1 & Head 2 & Head 3\\\hline\endfirsthead
  \hline
  \rowcolor{yellow}Head 1 & Head 2 & Head 3\\\hline\endhead
  \hline\endfoot
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  % attempt to insert multirows
  \multirow{2}{*}[0em]{Saturday} & \multirow{2}{*}[0em]{$17$} & \\
  & & \\
  % attempt to add a horizontal line
  \cline{2-3}
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\

\end{longtable}
        
\end{document}
```

This is how it currently looks:

[image]

Comment: note: I tried to add a horizontal line using ```\cline{2-3}```, just for a better readability of the table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Merge cells from the "bottom" with a negative number of cells. It seems that colours applied to rows overlap the text. If you move `\multirow` to the bottom, you let the text be typeset after the colours are applied.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\title{A random title}

% Add longtable and xcolor packages and define two colors
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{light-gray}{HTML}{E5E4E2}
\definecolor{light-cyan}{HTML}{E0FFFF}

% Add the multirow package
\usepackage{multirow, makecell}


\begin{document}
\maketitle

% Table
\rowcolors{1}{light-cyan}{light-gray}
\begin{longtable}{|*{3}{p{.3\textwidth}|}}
  \hiderowcolors
  \caption{Fine caption}\\
  \showrowcolors
  \hline
  \rowcolor{magenta}Head 1 & Head 2 & Head 3\\\hline\endfirsthead
  \hline
  \rowcolor{yellow}Head 1 & Head 2 & Head 3\\\hline\endhead
  \hline\endfoot
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  & & \\
  \multirow{-2}{*}[0em]{Saturday} & \multirow{-2}{*}[0em]{$17$} & \\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Additional variants of the code to keep the same background colour of "merged" cells--only snippets are provided whereas the rest of the code is the same.

A variant with resetting the counter `rownum` (based on answers in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170637/restarting-rowcolors))

```latex
\begin{longtable}{|*{3}{p{.3\textwidth}|}}
  \hiderowcolors
  \caption{Fine caption}\\
  \hline
  \rowcolor{magenta}%
  Head 1 & Head 2 & Head 3\\\hline\endfirsthead
  \hline
  \rowcolor{yellow}%
  Head 1 & Head 2 & Head 3\\\hline\endhead
  \hline\endfoot
  \showrowcolors
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  \global\rownum=1\relax% applies to the row after this one
  & & \\
  \multirow{-2}{*}[0em]{Saturday} & \multirow{-2}{*}[0em]{$17$} & \\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
\end{longtable}
```

[image]

A variant with an inner `tabular`:

```latex
% 
\begin{longtable}{|*{3}{p{.3\textwidth}|}}
  \hiderowcolors
  \caption{Fine caption}\\
  \showrowcolors
  \hline
  \rowcolor{magenta}Head 1 & Head 2 & Head 3\\\hline\endfirsthead
  \rowcolor{yellow} Head 1 & Head 2 & Head 3\\\hline\endhead
  \hline\endfoot
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Saturday  & $17$      & \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
                            A\\
                            B\\
                            C
                          \end{tabular} \\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
\end{longtable}
```

[image]

A variant with a "stretched" row via a strut:

```latex
\begin{longtable}{|*{3}{p{.3\textwidth}|}}
  \hiderowcolors
  \caption{Fine caption}\\
  \showrowcolors
  \hline
  \rowcolor{magenta}Head 1 & Head 2 & Head 3\\\hline\endfirsthead
  \rowcolor{yellow} Head 1 & Head 2 & Head 3\\\hline\endhead
  \hline\endfoot
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  \rule[\dimexpr-\baselineskip+0.5ex]{0pt}{2\baselineskip}%
  Saturday  & $17$      & \\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
\end{longtable}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot @Celdor! ....just a question...something I did not understand....... is it possible to have the same color for the two cells shared by the ```Saturday``` and by ```17``` texts ? Or maybe I misunderstood your answer... :-)

Comment: It's possible, although I wonder if merged rows are supposed to have the same colour, why do you apply `\multirow`?

Comment: Ah ok, Yes yes, I would need the same color for merged rows.... that would my final goal.. :-) I thought that by applying ```\multirow``` I could get merged rows (often, for just a few columns) for both text and colors..

Comment: I updated my answer and added some additional variants of your code. Depending of your final goal, `\multirow` might not be the best tool. Hope it helps.

Comment: Amazing, thanks a lot @Celdor!!! Do you think it is possible to add also horizontal lines, for example, as ```\cline{2-3}```?

Answer (score 4):

- As I see your table, you not need multi row cells.
- Using `\longtblr` of `tabularray` package enable to write concise table code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{light-gray}{HTML}{E5E4E2}
\definecolor{light-cyan}{HTML}{E0FFFF}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtblr}[
caption = {Fine caption},
  label = {tab:long}
                ]{vlines = {gray},
                 colspec = { *{3}{X[l]} },
                 row{odd} = {bg=light-cyan},
                 row{even}= {bg=light-gray},
                 row{1} = {bg=purple!80, c},
                 %
                 rowhead=1
                 }
    \toprule[gray]
Head 1      & Head 2    & Head 3    \\ 
    \midrule[gray]
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
\SetRow{ht=2\baselineskip}  
Saturday    & 17        &           \\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
Mondday     & 19        &   {A\\ B\\ C} \\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
  Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3\\
    \bottomrule
\end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Fantastic answer @Zarko!!! Can I accept both your and @Celdor's answers ?? 
.......A little question.... @Zarko, would it be possible to add horizontal lines among rows as well, for example, ```\cline{2-3}```?

Comment: @limone, of course. Just try and you will see what will happen.  But why you will add those lines? BTW, you should accept only one answer ... which solve your problem on the best (simple, concise, ...) way ;-)

Comment: thanks a lot for your nice comment! About the lines, it is just for aesthetic reasons / personal taste, and not for any technical reason or particular needs to fulfill.... btw, I am a bit embarrassed because both of your solutions are simple, concise and clear! I am very grateful to both, even if I can "accept" only one answer, many many thanks!